# How to fix Sequelize update issue?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I use MySQL ORM. But update method not working.

```
User.update({
  ResetPasswordToken : resetPasswordToken
},{
  where: {
      UserName: 'testuser'
  }
})
```

Sequelize Log:

Executing (default): UPDATE `Users` SET `ResetPasswordToken`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `UserName` = ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation of Sequelize, save method is used for updating an instance. Please check [this](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html) page for more detail.

This has been mentioned in the documentation:

If you change the value of some field of an instance, calling save again will update it accordingly:

```
    const jane = await User.create({ name: "Jane" });
    console.log(jane.name); // "Jane"
    jane.name = "Ada";
    // the name is still "Jane" in the database
    await jane.save();
    // Now the name was updated to "Ada" in the database!
```

Similarly, your code can be written as:

```
    const foo = async (resetPasswordToken) => {
       //Finding current instance of the user
       const currentUser = await User.findOne({
          where:{
            UserName: 'testuser'
          }
       });
       //modifying the related field
       currentUser.ResetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
       //saving the changes
       currentUser.save({fields: ['ResetPasswordToken']});
    }
```

Comment: I dont want create new user. I want to change old data. For example: change password

Comment: Yes, I modified the answer according to your question. First, you can find the current user instance and then save the related field. Just give it a try, I believe it should work.

Comment: What if I want to update multiple rows, not just one row, based on some condition. Why isn't the above update code not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update several fields at once with the set method:

```
const jane = await User.create({ name: "Jane" });

jane.set({
  name: "Ada",
  favoriteColor: "blue"
});
// As above, the database still has "Jane" and "green"
await jane.save();
// The database now has "Ada" and "blue" for name and favorite color
```